# Ending Python execution whilst keeping Matplotlib Pyplot open?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

Making a script that grabs the latest COVID-19 England figures and then displays it as a matplotlib line graph. Early stages, but just thought I'd give a bit of background.

---

```
def plot(cases,deaths):
    plt.show(block=False)
    cases.plot(x='Specimen date',y='Cumulative lab-confirmed cases',color='green')
    deaths.plot(x='Reporting date',y='Cumulative deaths',color='red')
    plt.show()
```

This is one of my .py scripts (make_graph.py) that is meant to draw the graph after the .csv files are downloaded and parsed.

```
# Then, parse the data: we only need the rows with 'England', and the date and cumulative values
imported = csv_parser()
cases_filtered_import = imported[0]
deaths_filtered_import = imported[1]

# Finally, make the graph

plot(cases_filtered_import,deaths_filtered_import)

# !! This is the end of the main.py file
```

My only issue is that I cannot get the plot windows to be separated from main.py. I want it so that the graphs are displayed and then the code finishes after, instead of having to close the windows before the code execution finishes.

**Any help would be appreciated.** I am aware that this is probably a duplicated question, but I cannot seem to find a solution that works.

Is it perhaps the way that I executing the program (making separate .py files for different functions, and then importing and executing them from the main.py script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an old question. The thing is that `matplotlib` plots are interactive, not static (you can change the scale), so they do require a thread to run. Hence the only way to detach a plot is to arrange a separate thread for it. Then you can call plots there, and proceed with your code. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

def my_plot(x, y):
  plt.scatter(y, x)
  plt.show()


p = Process(target=my_plot, args=(x, y))
p.start()

sleep(1)
print('keep going')

# At the end
p.join()
```

Comment: This works, but not on Mac OS Catalina. Apparently there were some new security features in High Sierra that broke fork(). Is there an alternative to using this, just so that I can maintain this across multiple operating systems?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SpiritedByte/acbbd9bccd145b88c0806dddb2ec423a

Comment: Otherwise, if I try to run outside of VS Code and instead run from terminal using 'python3 -u ...' instead I get this: https://gist.github.com/SpiritedByte/3d06d837144e7f1d8a9a20d0e79c1ade

Comment: I was totally unaware that Mac OS will be different in this regard. I am running Linux and have repeatedly seen the opinion that UNIX systems are largely identical when it comes to Python, except some specific libraries.

Comment: They are largely similar. From what I can gather, Objective-C has never been too friendly to _fork()_ and _exec()_, and it would either go great or fail horribly. Calling _+initialize_ and then _fork()_ seems to upset macOS, and it crashes the Python process to avoid a possible deadlock. There's some more information about it [here](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2017/6/5/Objective-C_and_fork_in_macOS_1013.html). I think I'll have to try and find a safer route.